# How to concatenate rows into one cell and add break line after each one using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, string-aggregation

I am using SQL Server 2017 and I am trying to create a query that concatenates the languages and Levels of Proficiency in one line for every Employee. The table that stores the info in my SQL Database is this for example:

[image: Table source]

And the  end result I would like to achieve is this:

[image: End Result]

Using Stuff function and xml path I have managed to create a select query that shows this:

[image: So far]

But I can't find a way to insert a break line. The query will be used as a datasource for an AspxGridview.

Any help?

Thank you in advance!

My query so far:

```
select distinct
p.PersonID,
STUFF
( (SELECT char(10) + l.Language+' ('+ (case  cvnl.Proficiency when  1 then 'Good'
                                                                    when 2 then 'Very Good'
                                                                    when 3 then 'Excellent'
                                                                    end )
                                                    +') ' FROM CV_NewLanguages cvnl
                                                            inner join Languages l on l.LanguageID = cvnl.LanguageID
    WHERE cvnl.PersonID = p.PersonID

    ORDER BY l.Language ASC FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Languages
from CV_Certifications cv
       inner join person p on cv.PersonID=p.PersonID
             inner join CV_NewLanguages cvnl on cvnl.PersonID=p.PersonID
               inner join Languages l on l.LanguageID=cvnl.LanguageID
where  active=1      
group by 
p.PersonID,
cvnl.Proficiency,
l.Language
order by p.PersonID
```

The result is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2KeE.png)

Comment: i tagged with SQL Server even though SQL Server 2015 is not a valid product.

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2015** - we had 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and soon 2019 - so which one are you **really** using?

Comment: You should back up a bit and post what you are ultimately trying to do. Is this a web application? What you're suggesting is not something you would handle "in" SQL Server. SQL Server is not excel. What you're explaining sounds a lot like Presentation Logic against a data set, so giving some context will help us help you.

Comment: I have posted what I am ultimately trying to do already. What excel has to do with this? I am using devexpress gridvew to show info about the languages level of Employees and I am trying to insert a break line after every language and level. Devexpress Gridview is a way of presenting data.

Comment: I agree with kevin_fitz. You should do that in the presentation layer not in SQL

Comment: AspxGridview works with SQLDatasources. Can't change the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using SQL server 2017 you can use STRING_AGG function

```
SELECT 
    p.PersonID, 
    STRING_AGG( Language + '(' + 
        CASE cvnl.Proficiency 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Good'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Very Good'
            THEN 3 THEN 'Excellent'
        END + ')'
    , CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) AS Languages
FROM CV_Certifications cv
JOIN person p on cv.PersonID = p.PersonID
JOIN CV_NewLanguages cvnl on cvnl.PersonID = p.PersonID
JOIN Languages l on l.LanguageID = cvnl.LanguageID
WHERE active=1      
GROUP BY p.PersonID,
ORDER BY p.PersonID
```

You mention that you need it for a AspxGridview, so you might need an HTML break too

```
SELECT 
    p.PersonID, 
    STRING_AGG( Language + '(' + 
        CASE cvnl.Proficiency 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Good'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Very Good'
            THEN 3 THEN 'Excellent'
        END + ')'
    , CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '<BR/>' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) AS Languages
FROM CV_Certifications cv
JOIN person p on cv.PersonID = p.PersonID
JOIN CV_NewLanguages cvnl on cvnl.PersonID = p.PersonID
JOIN Languages l on l.LanguageID = cvnl.LanguageID
WHERE active=1      
GROUP BY p.PersonID,
ORDER BY p.PersonID
```

If you are using an SQL previous version or you want to keep using STUFF you can REPLACE the comma from your STUFF's result

```
SELECT 
    p.PersonID,
    REPLACE(
        STUFF( (
            SELECT ',' + l.Language +' (' + 
            CASE cvnl.Proficiency 
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Good'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'Very Good'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'Excellent'
            END +') ' 
            FROM CV_NewLanguages cvnl
            JOIN Languages l on l.LanguageID = cvnl.LanguageID
            WHERE cvnl.PersonID = p.PersonID
            ORDER BY l.Language ASC 
            FOR XML PATH(''))
         , 1, 1, '')
    ,',',CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)) AS Languages
FROM person p  
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CV_Certifications cv WHERE cv.PersonID = p.PersonID)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CV_NewLanguages cvnl WHERE cvnl.PersonID = p.PersonID
AND active=1      
ORDER BY p.PersonID
```

I also took the freedom to tune your query a little

Comment: If I use CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) I get these symbols #x0D; . Also if I use <br/> I also get symbols and no line break.

Comment: If you use break lines or tags into the STUFF yes, you get those symbols because XML PATH, but did you already try with STRING_AGG??

Comment: Thank you for the effort. Tried the above solution you offered but still no break line after Proficiency Level. I have not tried with String_Agg yet...

Comment: If you want to see the break lines in your result window in SSMS you wont  see them... check in your GridView

Comment: And try also with the <br/> if not... but I'm pretty sure that it works

Comment: Tried you suggestion in a Gridview and the language and Proficiency are shown in the same row. I am checking the Gridview not the SSMS. Thanks though.

Comment: Even using '<BR/>'? no way!

Comment: It actually worked! The specified DevExpressGridview Column needs to have PropertiesTextEdit-EncodeHtml="false" in order to make the code to work, with <br/> or not. Damn you DevExpress Gridview... Thank you Daniel Brughera for your help and persistence!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution from Pinal.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/01/sql-server-difference-between-line-feed-n-and-carriage-return-r-t-sql-new-line-char/

I had used this long back while binding its output to a crystal report. Havent tried with an aspx gridview.

Comment: Sorry, it hasn't helped me so far.